# Export PowerPivot to web

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerpivot

I have created a couple of basic charts and tables using `PowerPivot`but can't seem to find a way to export the data to the web.

Saving the `Excel` document as `Web File` causes the filters and interactivity to stop working.

I have also read about `SharePoint` but I'm not entirely sure how this would work, hence why I am writing this post.

Could someone please explain to me how I will manage to export `PowerPivot` data to the web and how it will work when using `SharePoint`?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways :

1. You can upload your excel to `[Power Bi site][1]` after signing up on the site. This gives you some limited capabilities for free.
2. You can upload the excel to any O365 SharePoint site and view the power views and power pivot based charts/reports on the web using excel web view data part on excel online. This will show you all excels which have a power pivot data model size upto 10 MB
3. You can view these excels in power bi sites after adding the power bi plugin($20 /year/cal). This also allows Natural language query on the power pivot data model. Size limitation on power bi site is relaxed to 250 MB